# Number of substrings with exactly k distinct characters

Tags: algorithms, logic, combinatorics, mathematical-programming, mathematical-analysis

Given a string s and an int k, return an int representing the number of substrings (not unique) of s with exactly k distinct characters. If the given string doesn't have k distinct characters, return 0.

```
Input: s = "pqpqs", k = 2
Output: 7
Explanation: ["pq", "pqp", "pqpq", "qp", "qpq", "pq", "qs"]
```

I have this solution for it:

```
   def subarraysWithKDistinct(self, A, K):
        return self.atMostK(A, K) - self.atMostK(A, K - 1)

    def atMostK(self, A, K):
        count = collections.Counter()
        res = i = 0
        for j in range(len(A)):
            if count[A[j]] == 0: K -= 1
            count[A[j]] += 1
            while K < 0:
                count[A[i]] -= 1
                if count[A[i]] == 0: K += 1
                i += 1
            res += j - i + 1
        return res
```

What I don't understand is how does atMost(k) - atMost(k-1) gives the total number of substrings that have exactly k distinct characters? I tried different examples and it works. I understand how the code works but not how the final answer is computed after two-passes.

Can someone give me generic mathematical proof or intuition behind it?

Comment: If there are 26 people in the room aged at most 50 and 22 people aged at most 49, then there are 26 – 22 = 3 people in the room aged exactly 50.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`atMost(A, K)` computes the number of substrings with at most K distinct characters.

A substring with at most K distinct characters has either exactly K, or at most K-1, distinct characters. So, `atMost(A, K) - atMost(A, K-1)` is the number of substrings with exactly K distinct characters.